# Angular can't bind to variable

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this declared in my class:

```
somePair: KVPair;
```

Where KVPair is just a key value pair JSON.

Then in my displayFN I set it like so:

```
displayFn(pair: KVPair) {
    this.somePair = pair;
}
```

But when I console.log(somePair) outside of displayFn, it's undefined, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Did you try `console.log(this.somePair) `?

Comment: It works in displayFn, but not in another function that gets called after displayFn. It returns an undefined.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set it with a [displayWith] which was clearing somePair.

When I set it in (optionSelected)="someFunction($event.option.value)", the value stuck around.